# Entity Framework throwing an error when adding data without IDs

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I've a function which returns a list of tweets. Each element in that list has a lot of data, the tweet's text, location, user information, if it was a retweet, its time, retweet information, picture links, and a lot more data, lists of lists of data in each other.

I am using Linq2Twitter package which provides me with an object called Status which is what I am referring to as a Tweet.

This code fetches the data from my function: `var container = await DoPagedSearchAsync(context, this);`

My DBSet looks like this:

```
       public class TweetContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Status> Tweets { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to add the data with this code:

```
        using (var vontex = new TweetContext())
        {
            vontex.Tweets.AddRange(container);
            vontex.SaveChanges();
        }
```

And the following is the list of errors I get at run-time on the line: `vontex.Tweets.AddRange(container);` :

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> DataAcquirer.Models.Status: : EntityType 'Status' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.Coordinate: : EntityType 'Coordinate' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.Entities: : EntityType 'Entities' has no key defined. >Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.HashTagEntity: : EntityType 'HashTagEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.PhotoSize: : EntityType 'PhotoSize' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.VideoInfo: : EntityType 'VideoInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.Variant: : EntityType 'Variant' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.SymbolEntity: : EntityType 'SymbolEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.UrlEntity: : EntityType 'UrlEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.UserMentionEntity: : EntityType 'UserMentionEntity' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.Geometry: : EntityType 'Geometry' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.User: : EntityType 'User' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.BannerSize: : EntityType 'BannerSize' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   DataAcquirer.Models.Category: : EntityType 'Category' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   Tweets: EntityType: EntitySet 'Tweets' is based on type 'Status' that has no keys defined.
>   Coordinates: EntityType: EntitySet 'Coordinates' is based on type 'Coordinate' that has no keys defined.
>   Entities: EntityType: EntitySet 'Entities' is based on type 'Entities' that has no keys defined.
>   HashTagEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'HashTagEntities' is based on type 'HashTagEntity' that has no keys defined.
>   PhotoSizes: EntityType: EntitySet 'PhotoSizes' is based on type 'PhotoSize' that has no keys defined.
>   VideoInfoes: EntityType: EntitySet 'VideoInfoes' is based on type 'VideoInfo' that has no keys defined.
>   Variants: EntityType: EntitySet 'Variants' is based on type 'Variant' that has no keys defined.
>   SymbolEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'SymbolEntities' is based on type 'SymbolEntity' that has no keys defined.
>   UrlEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'UrlEntities' is based on type 'UrlEntity' that has no keys defined.
>   UserMentionEntities: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserMentionEntities' is based on type 'UserMentionEntity' that has no keys defined.
>   Geometries: EntityType: EntitySet 'Geometries' is based on type 'Geometry' that has no keys defined.
>   Users: EntityType: EntitySet 'Users' is based on type 'User' that has no keys defined.
>   BannerSizes: EntityType: EntitySet 'BannerSizes' is based on type 'BannerSize' that has no keys defined.
>   Categories: EntityType: EntitySet 'Categories' is based on type 'Category' that has no keys defined.

The class looks something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using LitJson;

namespace LinqToTwitter
{
 [XmlType(Namespace = "LinqToTwitter")]
 public class Status
 {
    public Status();
    public Status(JsonData status);

    public Annotation Annotation { get; set; }
    public List<Contributor> Contributors { get; set; }
    public Coordinate Coordinates { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public ulong CurrentUserRetweet { get; set; }
    public long Cursor { get; set; }
    public Cursors CursorMovement { get; set; }
    public EmbeddedStatus EmbeddedStatus { get; set; }
    public Entities Entities { get; set; }
    public bool ExcludeReplies { get; set; }
    public Entities ExtendedEntities { get; set; }
    public int? FavoriteCount { get; set; }
    public bool Favorited { get; set; }
    public FilterLevel FilterLevel { get; set; }
    public ulong ID { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeContributorDetails { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeEntities { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeMyRetweet { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeRetweets { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeUserEntities { get; set; }
    public string InReplyToScreenName { get; set; }
    public ulong InReplyToStatusID { get; set; }
    public ulong InReplyToUserID { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public bool Map { get; set; }
    public ulong MaxID { get; set; }
    public StatusMetaData MetaData { get; set; }
    public EmbeddedStatusAlignment OEmbedAlign { get; set; }
    public bool OEmbedHideMedia { get; set; }
    public bool OEmbedHideThread { get; set; }
    public string OEmbedLanguage { get; set; }
    public int OEmbedMaxWidth { get; set; }
    public bool OEmbedOmitScript { get; set; }
    public string OEmbedRelated { get; set; }
    public string OEmbedUrl { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
    public bool PossiblySensitive { get; set; }
    public Status QuotedStatus { get; set; }
    public ulong QuotedStatusID { get; set; }
    public int RetweetCount { get; set; }
    public bool Retweeted { get; set; }
    public Status RetweetedStatus { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Scopes { get; set; }
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public ulong SinceID { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public ulong StatusID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool TrimUser { get; set; }
    public bool Truncated { get; set; }
    public string TweetIDs { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public StatusType Type { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ulong UserID { get; set; }
    public List<ulong> Users { get; set; }
    public bool WithheldCopyright { get; set; }
    public List<string> WithheldInCountries { get; set; }
    public string WithheldScope { get; set; }
 }
}
```

The above model can not be edited. It comes with Linq2Twitter package.

Comment: use [Key] data annotations on your ID. check this link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I cannot edit the model, it comes with the package

Comment: Create a new Model and Transfer the data you need. Entity will not be able to save all that complex datatypes.

Comment: Entity won't save it as it is but it will be able to save it, I have saved genuinely complex models before. I would've created my own model but the model is really lengthy and complex. That is the soul reason I am using codefirst

Comment: "Entity won't save it as it is but it will be able to save it" Entity will not save that, as long you cant edit it..

Comment: Saving is not the primary concern, avoiding the 'ID' error is the actual concern at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach won't work. The Twitter API returns objects that are hierarchical and not relational. e.g. Here's a snippet of what LINQ to Twitter consumes:

```
{
  "retweeted":false,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
  "possibly_sensitive":false,
  "retweeted_status":{
     "retweeted":false,
     ...,
     "user":{
        "id":41754227,
        ...
     },
     ...
  },
  "contributors":null,
  "coordinates":{
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[
          -122.40060,
          37.78215
      ]
  },
  "place":null,
  "user":{
     "id":15411837,
     ...
  },
  "retweet_count":393,
  ...
}
```

LINQ to Twitter translates that into a `Tweet` type and the `Tweet` type has a few idioms to make it easier to build LINQ `where` clauses. The `Tweet` is still hierarchical.

To understand the hierarchical structure of the `Tweet`, notice that the JSON above has more complex objects under the `Tweet`, such as `retweeted_status` (RetweetedStatus in LINQ to Twitter), which is a `Tweet` type property of the `Tweet`, and `user` which is a `User` type property of the `Tweet`. Within `RetweetedStatus` and `User` are more complex objects.

Toward the problem you're seeing, notice the `coordinates` property. It does not have an `ID` as it's primarily a value. Perhaps it would have been better modeled as a struct for it's semantics, and maybe that's one of my take-aways here, but the fact is that it doesn't, and will never, have an `ID`. If you go through the list of items in your error message, you'll see that most of the errors are for value type objects like `coordinates`.

One approach is to not persist in a relational model and look for a NoSQL option that will meet your needs. e.g. MongoDB or Microsoft's new CosmosDB - there are countless more choices. I've taken this approach in my own code because, while the Twitter API is much more disciplined these days, it used to change unpredictably. That said, a relational approach might be doable these days. In this approach you can read the raw contents from Twitter like this:

```
string jsonResults = vontex.RawResults;
```

Then you can use Json.NET to pull out individual tweets.

Here's what I would do with a relational approach:

1. Use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). The small amount of time it will take to learn this tool will pay many dividends in not only this project but in the future.
2. Create your own `Tweet` object suitable for relational persistence.
3. Use relational references to refer retweeted statuses back to the original tweet.
4. Create a User table and create a reference from the `Tweet` to the `User`.
5. For all the value type objects, you have two options:
   a. If it's a single value, like `coordinates`, flatten it into the `Tweet`.
   b. If it's a multi-value, like `entities`, create a separate table where the entity has it's own pseudo-key and refers back to the `Tweet`.

I know you would like to see code. However, this is a huge job and writing code would be comparable to me writing your entire data access layer for you, which wouldn't be reasonable for a forum answer. I would still go the NoSQL route unless there's a hard requirement to go relational. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. Helped a lot, and yea, I do use automapper. For now I made my own model, flattened the data I required and am sticking with SQL for now because a significant amount of data is irrelevant for my project. Again, thanks a tonne for clearing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from Status and add something like this if you plan to create your Ids manually:

```
 [DatabaseGe‌​nerated(DatabaseGen‌​eratedOption.None)]
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

or use the Key attribute as astated in the comments (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

```
[Key]
 public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: note that both of these modifications have _extremely_ differing effects. DatabaseGeneratedOption.None just means the value is not generated by the database, the PK part is just done by naming conventions. That also means you do not need the [Key] Attribute in neither of these approaches. This means also that the second approach has no difference to just declaring the property, which also makes the column DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity, while the other has none (the only difference to straight code first conventions).

Comment: True, I forgot to talk about EF naming conventions, the point in my answer is the inheritance and the new Id property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at 
[System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117(v=vs.113).aspx)

You could create a map:

```
public class StatusMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Status>
{
     public StatusMap()
     {
         ToTable("StatusTable")
         .HasKey(p => p.ID);
     }
}
```

Then in your Context you would add:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating([NotNull] DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StatusMap());
}
```